# SeAndroid Make - Compile Error‏ system/core/init/init.c: In function 'service_start'

Tags: android, android-source

I'm having compiling error while trying to build the SeAndroid 4.2 project.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and gcc4.4

I followed the tutorial on SeAndroid Wiki and downloaded the whole source and after I tried to build a kernel.

*seandroid-tegra3-grouper-3.1-jb-mr1.1*  because I'm using a Asus TF700T device (with tegra chipset).

As mentioned on SeAndroid wiki page, I type

```
export PREFIX=/path/to/my/aospclone

cd $PREFIX/kernel/tegra

git checkout seandroid-tegra3-grouper-3.1-jb-mr1.1 

make ARCH=arm tegra3_android_defconfig

make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=$PREFIX/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin/arm-eabi-
```

The build completes correctly.

Then I'm trying to build my seandroid like :

```
cd $PREFIX
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch full_grouper-userdebug
make -j8
```

Then after 20 or 30 minutes of compiling, I got an error

```
...
system/core/init/init.c: In function 'service_start':

system/core/init/init.c:283:80: error: 'scon' undeclared (first use in this function)

system/core/init/init.c:283:80: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/init_intermediates/init.o] Error 1

make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
...
```

What could be the problem? I tried searching but couldn't find anything useful.